# Asynchronous validation with Template Driven Forms - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, asynchronous

Hi I'm having a hard time understanding how the async validation works in Angular forms. I've seen a lot of examples with "reactive forms" but I've been using "template driven forms" for this project for learning and it must be possible somehow hopefully.

**So what are my problem(s)?**

1. My backend are using the postalcode and country to get the specific area location. So far I can get the contact.country or my contact.postalcode value by using the control param in validate but not both. How do I get both?
2. how do I return this and use the value false to display a warning on my country and postalcode inputs?
3. (just for future projects) Is reactive forms the preferred way to go when using callback validation?

contacts-components.html

```
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="updatecountry" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{'createbuilding_step2_buildinginfoinput_country' | translate:'webbill': webLangModule}}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="country" id="updatecountry" [(ngModel)]="contact.country" #country="ngModel" appContactsValidator
                           oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
                           maxlength="2"
                           placeholder="{{'INITIALS' | translate}}">

                    <div *ngIf="country.invalid">
                        {{'_requiredmessage' | translate: 'webbill': webLangModule}}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="updatepostalcode" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{'contact_postcalcode' | translate:'webbill': webLangModule}}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                   <input name="postalcode" id="updatepostalcode" [(ngModel)]="contact.postalcode">
                </div>
            </div>
```

contacts.components.ts

```
    createContact(f: NgForm) {
        console.log(f.valid);
        if (f.valid === true) {
            this.buildingService.createContact(this.buildingNo, this.contact).subscribe(data => {
                this.modalService.dismissAll(data);
                this.listOfContacts.push(data);
                this.updateFilteredPersonTypes();
            }, err => {
                if (err.status === 500 || 404) {
                    alert(this.translateService.translate('_validationerror', 'webbill', this.webLangModule));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

contacts-validator.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appContactsValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS , useExisting: ContactsValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class ContactsValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  constructor(private buildingService: BuildingService) { }

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log(control.value);

    return new Promise(resolve =>
        this.buildingService.getPostalcodes(control.value, '2400').subscribe(res => {
          if (res === true) {
            resolve(null);
          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        }));  }

}
```

1. EDIT:
   If you have any questions regarding this post, feel free to ask me about it. Also if you have any good documentation on this subject feel free to post it.